# как работать с числами в файлах?

Tags: c, файлы, сортировка

Не понимаю, как работать с числами в файлах. Если представить задачу, где есть кол-во цифр, которое заранее известно, то тут дело понятно: `while(fscanf(f,%d,&i)>0)`, а там дальше по заданию. Но что делать с числами, если они не на одной строке? а если их нужно отсортировать как-либо в файле? записать все числа в массив, и уже оттуда с ними работать ведь не получится, переход как-то на другую строку реализовать-то надо. Проблемы появились с этой задачей:  Дан текстовый файл, в котором записаны только целые числа. Количество чисел в каждой строке может быть любым, но точно не больше 30. Разделителями между числами являются пробелы и/или знаки табуляции, символов-разделителей может быть больше одного. Требуется записать в новый текстовый файл номера строк исходного файла, последовательности чисел в которых являются строго возрастающими или строго убывающими. Числа записывать по десять в строку через один пробел

Comment: Если формат файла соответствует задаче, то сложностей быть не должно. Вы лучше конкретный пример, поставивший вас в тупик, в тексте своего вопроса приведите

Comment: *Смотрел в интернете, но ответа не нашел. Учебников и пособий под рукой нет* Значит, Интернет есть — тогда посмотрите [сюда](https://www.twirpx.com/files/science/informatics/languages/cpp/), например — там масска учебников и пособий не только по С++, но и по С.

Comment: @avp Дан текстовый файл, в котором записаны только целые числа. Количество чисел в каждой
строке может быть любым, но точно не больше 30. Разделителями между числами
являются пробелы и/или знаки табуляции, символов-разделителей может быть больше
одного. Требуется записать в новый текстовый файл номера строк исходного файла,
последовательности чисел в которых являются строго возрастающими или строго
убывающими. Числа записывать по десять в строку через один пробел. Задача просто в ступор ввела

Comment: @Harry для сайта vpn нужен?

Comment: Используете [getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), читаете файл по строкам и узнаете их номера. Для прохода по числам в строке можно использовать либо [strtoll](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll), либо [sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) (в нем обратите внимание на элемент формата `%n`)

Comment: @ualdrm Откуда мне знать, что у вас запрещено? :) Мне не нужен...

Comment: @Harry, я постоянно удивляюсь, что SO еще открывается...

Comment: @avp Зато в соседнем вопросе о "Сириусе" — *Доступ временно ограничен для вашего региона
Ограничение касается США, стран Европейского союза и других, являющихся источниками компьютерных атак.* :) Напугали ёжика голым задом...

Comment: Вот еще, прямо сейчас в Телеграме — https://t.me/c/1702270924/1671 — "Программирование на С для начинающих"...

Comment: @harry не открывает: «Вы не находитесь в группе, где было опубликовано это сообщение»

Comment: Ну что за беспомощность... Держите: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Nl1xtXLXmIRw9l-b_27L3kw4Rs0NVUj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @avp читал и читал как и с чем едят ваш getline и sscanf, но для себя чего понятного не нашел. Я так понял, что мне сначала нужно перенести все с файла в строку, после, с помощью sscanf, найти нужные мне строки, а далее с getline записать в файл номера, так?

Comment: Конечно, нет. С помощью getline вы в цикле построчно читаете файл `char *pstr = 0; size_t str_size = 0; while ((len = getline(&pstr, &str_size, infile)) > 0) { ...`. Далее вот в каком-то таком `for (int i = 0; (rc = sscanf(s, "%d%n", &v, &pos)) == 1; s += pos, i++) { ...` вложеном цикле, вызывая sscanf читаете все числа из этой строки (и заодно проверяете, образают ли они возрастающую или убывающую последовательность. Если образуют, то после цикла обычным fprintf-ом записываете номер этой строки в выходной файл). При выходе из цикла rc == 0 будет означать ошибку ввода числа, а rc == -1 -- ОК

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skipws` (skip whitespaces) останавливается или перед первым найденным не пробелом ([ungetc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ungetc)), или после конца строки, или в конце файла. В `*read` попадает количество прочитанных символов (потом пригодится). Удобно чтобы считать строки:

```
int skipws(FILE *f, int *read) {
    for (int n = 0; ; ++n) {
        const int c = fgetc(f);
        if (c == EOF) {
            *read = n;
            return c;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
            *read = n + 1;
            return c;
        }
        if (!isspace((unsigned char)c)) {
            ungetc(c, f);
            *read = n;
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

`print` печатает числа по десять штук в строке. Параметр `*n_prints` хранит состояние (чтобы знать когда переводить строки или выводить пробелы), перед первым вызовом его надо обнулить:

```
void print(int n, int *n_prints) {
    if (*n_prints == 10) {
        putchar('\n');
        *n_prints = 0;
    }
    if (*n_prints > 0) {
        putchar(' ');
    }
    printf("%d", n);
    ++*n_prints;
}
```

Полное решение задачи:

```
int main() {
    int n_prints = 0;
    for (int n_line = 1; ; ++n_line) {
        bool dsc = true;
        bool asc = true;
        int prev_n;
        for (int k = 0; ; ++k) {
            int read;
            const int c = skipws(stdin, &read);
            if (asc || dsc) {
                if ((c == EOF && (k > 0 || read > 0)) || c == '\n') {
                    print(n_line, &n_prints);
                }
            }

            if (c == EOF) {
                return 0;
            }

            if (c == '\n') {
                break;
            }

            int n;
            if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (k > 0) {
                asc &= prev_n < n;
                dsc &= prev_n > n;
            }
            prev_n = n;
        }

    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```